# firefox - autocomplete feature

Tags: firefox, internet, windows-explorer, autocomplete

Internet Explorer has one feature called - AutoComplete. My query is what is the name of similar feature in Firefox? From where and how can we enable/disable the AutoComplete feature in Firefox?

Comment: Why make it a wiki?

Answer (score 1):

http://dougal.gunters.org/blog/2004/12/15/firefox-inline-autocomplete

Quote:

```
To turn on inline autocomplete in the Firefox web browser…

Enter about:config in the URL field
Right-click on the page and create a new Boolean value
Enter browser.urlbar.autoFill as the preference name (note, case-sensitive: ‘F’, not ‘f’)
Set the value to true
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read this: [Changing autocomplete behavior - Firefox.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Disabling_autocomplete_-_Firefox)